# When are functions analytically extendible to the real line?

Tags: complex-analysis

To illustrate my question, consider the function $f(z):=\log\cosh(z)$. This function is real and analytic on the real line, but it is not entire (e.g. it has singularities at $(\frac12+\mathbb Z)\pi i$. Suppose now that we Taylor expand $f$ around the point $z=0$. Can we somehow read off from the coefficients of this expansion that the function is analytic on $\mathbb R$?

In practice, I have a function $g(z)$ (taking real values on the real line) and I can explicitly calculate a finite number of derivatives at $z=0$. I know that the radius of convergence around $z=0$ is positive. However, I do not have a generic way to calculate/guess all of them. I hope to be able to prove some bounds on the higher order derivatives and then conclude that the Taylor expansion of $g$ at $z=0$ can be analytically extended to $\mathbb R$. Like before, I expect that $g$ is not entire because I expect to find some singularities away from the real line.

Any help/references are appreciated. Of course, there may be multiple criteria which may be helpful in this case. Many thanks!

Comment: generally, analytic continuation at the boundary of a power series doesn't depend on bounds for the Taylor coefficients if the function is not entire so the power series converges everywhere; in other words, the only way bounds tell you something is if they tell you all, so the function is entire; otherwise, if the function is not entire and has radius $R$, continuation even at $\pm R$ is a very delicate issue and depends more on the regularity of the coefficients (for example if all coefficients are of the same sign or alternate signs, there is no continuation, same if too many are zero etc)